# Command to update only one ChangeSet : Mvn liquibase command?

Tags: maven, liquibase

Normally to execute all the change set in a file : we use command :

```
mvn liquibase:update
```

What should I use If I want to execute to 'specific' Changeset out of many ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is to use labels on your changesets, and then see if you can get the maven plugin to do a deploy with labels. Labels are a fairly new feature, and it may be that the Maven plugin will need to be updated to provide support for labels. It appears that the Liquibase Maven plugin is currently using Liquibase 3.2, and labels were introduced in 3.3.